# Modify a JSON file with Julia

Tags: json, julia

I have implemented an algorithm in Julia, and I would like to compile the results of this algorithm in a JSON file. My idea for how this should operate is to have a file holding the results of previous calculations, and when a new calculation is run I will add the new result to the file.

However, I can not understand how to properly modify the file in place, resulting in this solution where the entire file is read in, deleted, and a new file is created. What is a better way to do this?
Here is my code

```
using JSON

newentry = Dict(string(θ) => list[end].legs[2][1]/2.0)

open("RayDictionary.txt","r") do file
    d = JSON.parse(file)
end

merge!(d,newentry)

rm("RayDictionary.txt")

open("RayDictionary.txt","w") do file
    JSON.print(file,d,2)
end
```

Comment: I think it would be easier for you to work with JSONLines format as it allows for easy appending to a file of new records.

Comment: Agreed: serialized JSON objects are not designed for appending new data. You will have to at least delete the closing delimiter representing the end of the JSON dictionary before appending new keys, meaning you are going to be backtracking through the file no matter what. In addition to JSONLines, you might also want to check out YAML, which allows appending key: value pairs to the end of a document, and which allows you to serialize multiple JSON documents to the same file (as JSON is a subset of YAML).

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved using external to Julia tools (yeah, not the most Julian way, but pragmatic enough).

A utility called `jq` will do the JSON updating, and another utility `sponge` will overcome the in-place editing problem.

On my system, in the Bash shell, I install them using:

```
apt-get install jq
apt-get install moreutils
```

Other systems should have a similar setup procedure (see the utilities' web-sites for help on non apt-get systems).

If a file `RayDictionary.txt` is initialized with:

```
{
}
```

then, in Julia:

```
json_filename = "RayDictionary.txt"
new_key = string(θ)
new_value = string(list[end].legs[2][1]/2.0)
run(pipeline(
  `jq '. + { "'$new_key'": "'$new_value'" }' $json_filename`,
  `sponge $json_filename`
))
```

will add a key to the file.

This code may need tweaking, but the ingredients for making a simple working solution are here. For example, the file might be required to exist and initialized with a `{ }` to receive keys from above code. The exact JSON structure needs to be considered.